# Is there a way to make apt report which packages in a dist-upgrade will use additional disk space?

Tags: debian, apt, disk-usage

I recently decided it was time to do the ol' dist-upgrade.

Since I don't upgrade often, I got this message:

```
deus@machina:~/$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cmap-adobe-japan1 gnuplot-nox gs-cjk-resource kdebase-data kdebase-runtime-data kdebase-workspace-data
  kdebase-workspace-kgreet-plugins koffice-libs krita libept1 libgd2-noxpm libgdl-3-1 libleptonica libmlt4 libmp3splt-mp3
  libmp3splt-ogg libplasmaclock4abi1 libscience4 libtaskmanager4abi1 libupnp3 octave3.2 xz-lzma
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptitude-common avogadro-data cpp-4.7 cryptsetup-bin fonts-freefont-ttf fonts-lyx fonts-stix fonts-vlgothic g++-4.7
  g++-4.7-multilib gcc-4.7 gcc-4.7-multilib gcj-4.7-base gcj-4.7-jre-lib gfortran-4.7 gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
  gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-x icedtea-7-jre-cacao kajongg kalgebra-common kate-data
  katepart kde-baseapps kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-style-oxygen kde-wallpapers
  kde-wallpapers-default kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins
  kdegraphics-mobipocket kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdegraphics-thumbnailers kmenuedit kmod ksaneplugin ktouch-data
  lib32itm1 libanalitza4abi1 libanalitzagui4 libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12 libasprintf0c2 libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatlas3-base libatomicparsley0 libavahi-client-dev libavahi-common-dev libavogadro1
  libbabl-0.1-0 libblas3 libboost-graph1.49.0 libboost-iostreams1.49.0 libboost-program-options1.49.0 libboost-python1.49.0
  libboost-regex1.49.0 libcaca-dev libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcmis-0.2-0 libcryptsetup4 libcrystalhd3
  libdb5.1-java-jni libdbus-1-dev libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libept1.4.12 libexiv2-12
  libexttextcat-data libexttextcat0 libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcj13 libgd2-xpm libgdl-3-2 libgegl-0.2-0 libgettextpo0
  libgusb2 libindi-data libindi0b libiso9660-8 libitm1 libkactivities-bin libkactivities6 libkasten1controllers1
  libkasten1core1 libkasten1gui1 libkasten1okteta1controllers1 libkasten1okteta1core1 libkasten1okteta1gui1
  libkateinterfaces4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw20 libkdeclarative5 libkexiv2-10 libkexiv2-data libkipi-data libkiten4abi1
  libkmod2 libksane-data libktorrent4 libkwineffects1abi3 libkwinglutils1 libkworkspace4abi1 liblapack3 liblensfun-data
  liblensfun0 liblept3 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libmarblewidget13 libmediastreamer1 libmlt5
  libmp3splt0-mp3 libmp3splt0-ogg libmtdev1 libnova-0.14-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libokteta1core1 libokteta1gui1 libopenbabel4
  libopus0 libplasmaclock4abi3 libpoppler-glib8 libprison0 libpulse-dev libqalculate5-data libqrencode3 libqt4-dev-bin
  libqtlocation1 libslang2-dev libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsox2 libspnav0
  libstdc++6-4.7-dev libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtbb2 libtokyocabinet9 libts-dev libupnp6
  libusbredirparser0 libvirtodbc0 libvisio-0.0-0 libvorbisidec1 libwebrtc-audio-processing-0 libwireshark2 libwiretap2
  libwsutil2 libxcb-glx0 libxz-java linux-headers-3.2.0-3-amd64 linux-headers-3.2.0-3-common odbcinst odbcinst1debian2
  python-avogadro python-dbus-dev python-openssl python-pam python-qt4-sql python-serial python-twisted-bin
  python-twisted-core python-zope.interface sharutils svgpart valgrind-dbg virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin
  virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  acl acpi-fakekey acpi-support acpi-support-base acpid adduser akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akonadiconsole
  akregator alsa-utils amor anacron anjuta-common apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common apbs apt
  apt-listchanges apt-utils aptitude ark at autopoint autotools-dev avahi-autoipd base-files base-passwd bash
  bash-completion bind9-host binutils blinken blogilo bluetooth bluez bluez-alsa bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer bomber bovo
  bridge-utils bsdmainutils bsdutils bsnes busybox bzip2 ca-certificates ca-certificates-java cabal-install camlp4 cantor
  cantor-backend-kalgebra cdbs cdrdao cervisia chocolate-doom cmake cmake-data colord console-setup console-setup-linux
  consolekit coreutils cpio cpp cpp-4.6 cpufrequtils cron cuneiform cuneiform-common cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common
  cups-driver-gutenprint cups-filters cups-ppdc curl cvs cvsservice darcs dash db5.1-util dbus dbus-x11
  dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service debconf debconf-i18n debhelper debian-archive-keyring debianutils default-jre
  default-jre-headless desktop-base dictionaries-common diffutils dirmngr discover djview-plugin djview4 djvulibre-bin
  djvulibre-desktop dkms dmidecode dmsetup dnsmasq-base dnsutils docbook-xml dolphin dosfstools dpkg dpkg-dev dragonplayer
  dvdauthor e2fslibs e2fsprogs ed edict eject emacsen-common espeak espeak-data exim4 exim4-base exim4-config
  exim4-daemon-light exiv2 fakeroot fdupes festival ffmpeg ffmpegthumbs file filelight flashplugin-nonfree fontconfig
  fontconfig-config fonts-droid fonts-liberation fonts-opensymbol foo2zjs foomatic-db foomatic-db-engine foomatic-filters
  freeglut3 freespacenotifier ftp fuse g++ g++-4.6 g++-4.6-multilib g++-multilib gawk gcc gcc-4.4-base gcc-4.6 gcc-4.6-base
  gcc-4.6-multilib gcc-4.7-base gcc-multilib gcj-4.6-base gcj-4.6-jre-lib gconf-service gconf2 gconf2-common gdb gdb-doc
  gdbserver geoip-database get-flash-videos get-iplayer gettext gettext-base gfortran gfortran-4.6 ghc ghostscript
  ghostscript-cups gimp gimp-data gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 git git-man glib-networking
  glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-icon-theme gnupg gnupg-agent gnupg2 gnuplot gnuplot-x11 golang
  golang-doc golang-go golang-src google-chrome-stable google-gadgets-common google-gadgets-gst google-gadgets-qt gpgsm
  gpgv gpsd granatier grep groff groff-base grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gsettings-desktop-schemas
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gtkpod gtkpod-data gvfs gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-libs gwenview
  gzip hdparm host hpijs hpijs-ppds hplip hplip-cups hplip-data hyphen-en-us icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm
  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common iceweasel iceweasel-l10n-en-gb idle idle-python2.7 ifrit ifupdown
  imagemagick imagemagick-common info initramfs-tools initscripts insserv install-info installation-report iproute iptables
  ipython isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common iso-codes iw jackd2 jackd2-firewire java-common jovie juk k3b k3b-data
  kaccessible kaddressbook kalarm kalgebra kalzium kalzium-data kamera kanagram kanjidic kapman kapptemplate kate katomic
  kbattleship kbd kblackbox kblocks kbounce kbreakout kbruch kcachegrind kcalc kcharselect kcolorchooser kde-config-cddb
  kde-config-cron kde-full kde-icons-mono kde-l10n-engb kde-plasma-desktop kde-plasma-netbook kde-standard
  kde-window-manager kdeaccessibility kdeadmin kdeartwork kdeartwork-emoticons kdeartwork-style kdeartwork-theme-window
  kdebase-apps kdebase-bin kdebase-runtime kdebase-workspace kdebase-workspace-bin kdeedu kdeedu-kvtml-data kdegames
  kdegames-card-data kdegames-mahjongg-data kdegraphics kdegraphics-libs-data kdegraphics-strigi-plugins kdelibs-bin
  kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork kdenetwork-filesharing kdenlive
  kdenlive-data kdepasswd kdepim kdepim-groupware kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepim-wizards
  kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdeplasma-addons kdesdk kdesdk-dolphin-plugins kdesdk-kio-plugins kdesdk-misc kdesdk-scripts
  kdesdk-strigi-plugins kdetoys kdeutils kdewallpapers kdewebdev kdf kdiamond kdm kdoctools keyboard-configuration
  kfilereplace kfind kfourinline kgamma kgeography kgeography-data kget kgoldrunner kgpg khangman khelpcenter4 kig kigo
  killbots kimagemapeditor kinfocenter kiriki kismet kiten kjots kjumpingcube kleopatra klettres klettres-data klibc-utils
  klickety klines klinkstatus klipper kmag kmahjongg kmail kmines kmix kmousetool kmouth kmplot kmtrace knetwalk knode
  knotes kolf kollision kolourpaint4 kommander kompare konq-plugins konqueror konqueror-nsplugins konquest konsole
  konsolekalendar kontact kopete korganizer kpartloader kpat kppp krb5-locales krdc kremotecontrol kreversi krfb krita-data
  krosspython kruler kscd kscreensaver kscreensaver-xsavers kshisen ksirk ksnapshot kspaceduel ksquares kstars kstars-data
  ksudoku ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog kteatime ktimer ktimetracker ktorrent ktorrent-data ktouch ktron ktuberling
  kturtle ktux kubrick kuiviewer kuser kwalletmanager kwordquiz kwrite laevateinn lame latex-beamer latex-xcolor
  leptonica-progs less lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32gomp1 lib32ncurses5 lib32quadmath0 lib32stdc++6 lib32tinfo5
  lib32v4l-0 lib32z1 libaa1 libaacs0 libacl1 libaio1 libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4
  libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libanjuta-3-0 libao-common libao4 libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libarchive12 libarpack2 libart-2.0-2 libasound2 libasound2-dev
  libasound2-plugins libatasmart4 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatlas3gf-base libattr1 libaudio2 libaudiofile1 libav-tools
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-glib1 libavcodec53 libavdevice53 libavfilter2
  libavformat53 libavutil51 libbind9-80 libblas-dev libblas3gf libblkid1 libbluetooth3 libbluray-bdj libbluray1
  libbrlapi0.5 libbsd-dev libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libbz2-dev libc-ares2 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev
  libc6-dev-i386 libc6-i386 libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2 libcairo2-dev
  libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra0 libcap-ng0 libcdaudio1 libcdt4 libcfitsio3 libcgraph5
  libck-connector0 libcln6 libcolord1 libcomerr2 libcommons-beanutils-java libcommons-compress-java libconfig++9
  libconfig-inifiles-perl libcpufreq0 libcroco3 libcrypto++9 libcuneiform0 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1
  libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcwidget3 libdatetime-perl libdb-java
  libdb5.1 libdb5.1-java libdb5.1-java-gcj libdbus-1-3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdc1394-22 libdconf0 libdevmapper1.02.1
  libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdiscover2 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libdns81 libdpkg-perl
  libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libedit2 libespeak1 libestools2.1
  libevent-2.0-5 libexif12 libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libfaad2 libffado2 libfftw3-3 libflite1 libfltk1.1 libfontconfig1
  libfontconfig1-dev libfontenc1 libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libfribidi0 libfs6 libftdi1 libfuse2 libgadu3 libgail-3-0
  libgail18 libgavl1 libgc1c2 libgcc1 libgcj-bc libgcj-common libgcj12 libgconf-2-4 libgconf2-4 libgdbm3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgdl-3-common libgeoip1 libgfortran3 libggadget-1.0-0b libggadget-qt-1.0-0b libghc-dataenc-dev
  libghc6-dataenc-dev libgif4 libgimp2.0 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglib2.0-dev libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
  libgmp-dev libgmp10 libgmpxx4ldbl libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnutls-dev libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26
  libgnutls28 libgnutlsxx27 libgomp1 libgpgme++2 libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port0 libgpm2 libgps20 libgraph4
  libgraphicsmagick++3 libgraphicsmagick3 libgraphite2-2.0.0 libgs9 libgs9-common libgsm1 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssglue1
  libgssrpc4 libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin
  libgtk2.0-common libgtkpod1 libgutenprint2 libgvc5 libgvpr1 libhdf5-7 libhogweed2 libhpmud0 libhtml-form-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-date-perl libhyphen0 libical0 libice-dev libice6 libicu48 libid3-3.8.3c2a
  libidn11 libilmbase6 libimobiledevice2 libio-socket-ssl-perl libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82 libiscsi1 libjack-jackd2-0
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjim0debian2 libjline-java libjpeg62 libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc
  libjson0 libjtidy-java libk3b6 libk3b6-extracodecs libk5crypto3 libkabc4 libkadm5clnt-mit8 libkadm5srv-mit8
  libkatepartinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcmutils4 libkdb5-6 libkde3support4
  libkdecorations4 libkdecore5 libkdeedu-data libkdegames5a libkdepim4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4
  libkeduvocdocument4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkeyutils1 libkfile4 libkggzgames4 libkggzmod4 libkggznet4
  libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkimproxy4 libkio5 libkipi8 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkleo4
  libklibc libkmahjongglib4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4
  libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkonqsidebarplugin4a libkontactinterface4 libkopete4 libkparts4
  libkpathsea6 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkrb5-3
  libkrb5support0 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libkrossui4 libksane0 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4
  libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libkunitconversion4 libkutils4 libkxmlrpcclient4
  liblapack-dev liblapack3gf liblcms1 liblcms2-2 libldap-2.4-2 libleptonica-dev liblockfile-bin liblockfile1 liblqr-1-0
  libltdl7 liblua5.1-0 liblvm2app2.2 liblwres80 liblzma5 libmagic1 libmailtools-perl libmailtransport4 libmessagecore4
  libmessagelist4 libmicroblog4 libmimelib4 libmlt++3 libmlt-data libmodplug1 libmount1 libmouse-perl libmozjs10d
  libmp3lame0 libmp3splt0 libmpcdec6 libmpfr4 libmpg123-0 libmsn0.3 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmusicbrainz3-6
  libmysqlclient18 libncurses5 libncurses5-dev libncursesw5 libneon27-gnutls libnepomuk4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4
  libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnetpbm10 libnettle4 libnewt0.52 libnfsidmap2 libnl-3-200
  libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libnspr4-0d
  libnss3-1d libnuma1 libofa0 libogg-dev libogg0 libokularcore1 libopenal-data libopenal-dev libopenal1 libopencore-amrnb0
  libopencore-amrwb0 libopencv-calib3d2.3 libopencv-contrib2.3 libopencv-core2.3 libopencv-features2d2.3 libopencv-flann2.3
  libopencv-highgui2.3 libopencv-imgproc2.3 libopencv-legacy2.3 libopencv-ml2.3 libopencv-objdetect2.3 libopencv-video2.3
  libopenexr6 libopenjpeg2 libopenmpi1.3 libopenraw1 liborc-0.4-0 libortp8 libotr2 libpam-ck-connector libpam-modules
  libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g libpango1.0-0 libpango1.0-dev libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpari-gmp3
  libparpack2 libparted0debian1 libpathplan4 libpcap0.8 libpci3 libpciaccess0 libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0
  libpcsclite1 libperl5.14 libphonon4 libpipeline1 libpixman-1-0 libpixman-1-dev libplasma-geolocation-interface4
  libplasma-ruby libplasma3 libplasmagenericshell4 libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpoppler-qt4-3 libpopt0 libpostproc52 libpq5 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libprocps0
  libproxy0 libptexenc1 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpython2.7 libpython3.2 libqalculate5 libqca2
  libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-dev libqt4-help libqt4-network
  libqt4-opengl libqt4-opengl-dev libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql
  libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4 libqtcore4-perl
  libqtgui4 libqtgui4-perl libqtruby4shared2 libqtwebkit-dev libqtwebkit4 libquadmath0 libquicktime2 librados2 libraptor1
  libraptor2-0 librasqal3 libraw1394-11 librbd1 librdf0 libreoffice libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-filter-binfilter
  libreoffice-filter-mobiledev libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common
  libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-math libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-style-galaxy libreoffice-style-oxygen
  libreoffice-writer libroar-compat2 libroar2 librpcsecgss3 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libruby1.8 libsamplerate0 libsane
  libsane-common libsane-hpaio libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libschroedinger-1.0-0 libscim8c2a libsdl-gfx1.2-4
  libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-net1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsdl1.2-dev libsdl1.2debian libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage1
  libsensors4 libsepol1 libservlet2.5-java libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libslang2 libslv2-9 libsm-dev libsm6 libsmbclient libsmi2ldbl
  libsmokebase3 libsmokekdecore4-3 libsmokekdeui4-3 libsmokekfile3 libsmokekhtml3 libsmokekio3 libsmokeknewstuff2-3
  libsmokeknewstuff3-3 libsmokekparts3 libsmokektexteditor3 libsmokekutils3 libsmokenepomuk3 libsmokeplasma3
  libsmokeqtcore4-3 libsmokeqtdbus4-3 libsmokeqtgui4-3 libsmokeqtnetwork4-3 libsmokeqtopengl4-3 libsmokeqtsql4-3
  libsmokeqtsvg4-3 libsmokeqtwebkit4-3 libsmokeqtxml4-3 libsmokesolid3 libsndfile1 libsndfile1-dev libsnmp-base libsnmp15
  libsolid4 libsoprano4 libsoundtouch0 libsoup2.4-1 libsox-fmt-all libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-ao libsox-fmt-base
  libsox-fmt-ffmpeg libsox-fmt-mp3 libsox-fmt-oss libsox-fmt-pulse libspandsp2 libspectre1 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1
  libspice-server1 libsqlite3-0 libss2 libssh2-1 libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.6-dev
  libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libsvga1 libsvn1 libswscale2 libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni
  libswt-gtk-3-java libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libsyndication4 libsysfs2 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libtar0
  libtasn1-3 libtasn1-3-dev libtdb1 libthai-data libthai0 libtheora0 libthreadweaver4 libtiff4 libtinfo-dev libtinfo5
  libts-0.0-0 libupower-glib1 liburi-perl libusb-1.0-0 libustr-1.0-1 libuuid1 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libva-x11-1
  libvcdinfo0 libvdpau1 libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvlc5 libvlccore5 libvncserver0 libvo-aacenc0
  libvo-amrwbenc0 libvorbis-dev libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvpx1 libvtk5.8 libwavpack1 libwbclient0
  libweather-ion6 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwireshark-data
  libwpd-0.9-9 libwps-0.2-2 libwrap0 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-dev libx11-doc
  libx11-protocol-perl libx11-xcb1 libx86-1 libxapian22 libxau-dev libxau6 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-keysyms1
  libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xv0
  libxcb1 libxcb1-dev libxcursor1 libxdmcp-dev libxdmcp6 libxdot4 libxerces2-java libxext-dev libxext6 libxfont1 libxft-dev
  libxft2 libxi6 libxine1 libxine1-bin libxine1-ffmpeg libxine1-misc-plugins libxine1-plugins libxine1-x libxinerama1
  libxkbfile1 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-sax-perl libxml-simple-perl libxml2 libxml2-utils libxmuu1 libxrender-dev
  libxrender1 libxslt1.1 libxss1 libxt-dev libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxvidcore4 libxvmc1 libxxf86dga1 libzbar0
  libzvbi-common libzvbi0 linux-base linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-3.2 linux-libc-dev locales login logrotate lokalize
  lsb-base lsb-release lskat lsof luatex lynx lynx-cur make man-db manpages manpages-dev marble marble-data marble-plugins
  mawk mednafen melt mesa-common-dev mgltools-geomutils mgltools-gle mgltools-opengltk mgltools-pyglf mgltools-utpackages
  mgltools-vision mgltools-visionlibraries mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager module-init-tools mount mp3splt
  mpg123 mpg321 mplayer mtools multiarch-support mutt myspell-en-gb myspell-en-us mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mythes-en-us nano ncurses-base ncurses-bin ncurses-term netbase
  netcat-traditional netpbm network-manager network-manager-openvpn network-manager-pptp network-manager-vpnc nfs-common
  nfs-kernel-server notification-daemon ntfs-3g ntfsprogs ocaml ocaml-base ocaml-base-nox ocaml-interp ocaml-nox okteta
  okular openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
  openjdk-7-jre-lib openprinting-ppds openssh-client openssl openvpn os-prober oss-compat oxygen-icon-theme oxygencursors
  palapeli palapeli-data pari-doc pari-gp parley parley-data passwd pciutils pcmciautils pdf2djvu perl perl-base
  perl-modules phonon phonon-backend-vlc php5 plasma-containments-addons plasma-dataengines-addons
  plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-desktopthemes-artwork plasma-netbook plasma-runners-addons
  plasma-scriptengine-googlegadgets plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-scriptengine-ruby
  plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba plasma-scriptengine-webkit plasma-scriptengines plasma-wallpapers-addons
  plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-lancelot plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widgets-addons
  plasma-widgets-workspace policykit-1 poppler-data poppler-utils powertop poxml ppp pptp-linux preview-latex-style
  printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs printer-driver-postscript-hp
  printer-driver-ptouch procmail procps psmisc psutils pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-x11
  pulseaudio-utils pymol python python-apt python-apt-common python-beautifulsoup python-configobj python-crypto
  python-dateutil python-dbus python-debianbts python-decorator python-dev python-feedparser python-gi python-gobject
  python-gobject-2 python-kde4 python-libxml2 python-minimal python-numpy python-pexpect python-pip python-qt4
  python-qt4-dbus python-reportbug python-simplegeneric python-simplejson python-simpy python-simpy-doc python-simpy-gui
  python-sip python-support python-sympy python-tk python-uno python2.6 python2.6-minimal python2.7 python2.7-dev
  python2.7-minimal python3.2 python3.2-minimal qdbus qemu-keymaps qemu-kvm qemu-utils qjackctl qt4-linguist-tools
  qt4-qmake r-doc-html reportbug rocs rpcbind rsync rsyslog ruby-kde4 ruby-plasma ruby-qt4 ruby-qt4-webkit ruby1.8
  sane-utils scdaemon seabios sed sensible-utils sgml-base sgml-data shared-desktop-ontologies shared-mime-info
  soprano-daemon sox ssl-cert step subversion sudo sweeper system-config-printer-kde systemsettings sysv-rc sysvinit
  sysvinit-utils task-british task-british-desktop task-british-kde-desktop task-desktop task-laptop tasksel tasksel-data
  tcc tcl-vtk tcl8.5 tcpd tcpdump tex-common texinfo texlive-binaries texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc
  texlive-pstricks time tipa tk8.5 traceroute translate-toolkit transmission transmission-cli transmission-common
  transmission-gtk tsconf ttf-dejavu ttf-dejavu-core ttf-dejavu-extra ttf-freefont ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-liberation ttf-lyx
  ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-wqy-zenhei tzdata tzdata-java ucf udisks ufraw-batch umbrello uno-libs3 unp unrar-free unzip
  update-inetd upower ure usb-modeswitch-data usbutils util-linux util-linux-locales valgrind vavoom vcdimager vgabios
  vim-common vim-tiny visualboyadvance vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse vpnc w3m wget whiptail whois
  wireshark wireshark-common wpasupplicant x11-apps x11-common x11-utils x11-xfs-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-xext-dev xauth xchat xchat-common xclip xfonts-mathml
  xfonts-utils xinit xml-core xorg xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl
  xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod xserver-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-apm xserver-xorg-video-ark xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-chips xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-i128 xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64
  xserver-xorg-video-mga xserver-xorg-video-neomagic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-rendition xserver-xorg-video-s3
  xserver-xorg-video-s3virge xserver-xorg-video-savage xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident xserver-xorg-video-tseng
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xserver-xorg-video-voodoo xterm xtrans-dev xulrunner-10.0 xz-utils
  youtube-dl zip zlib1g zlib1g-dev
1568 upgraded, 183 newly installed, 22 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,433 MB of archives.
After this operation, 853 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

It could be that a lot of those packages are not really necessary for me, so if 853 MB is needed to upgrade those, then it's about 853 MB too large.

However, I have no way to ascertain this currently.

Of course `apt` should theoretically be able to print that information verbosely, if it can do the two sums in the first place.

Comment: Well, the information is there. Run `apt-cache show your-package`, and if the package is upgradeable, it'll show you two entries. Just subtract the `Installed-Size` of the installed from the `Installed-Size` of the latest. Is this information what you were looking for, or do you want help doing a script to calculate that automatically?

Comment: If they're not necessary then they shouldn't be installed. Apt will only install packages you *ask* for or *are required by* packages you asked for. When you `dist-upgrade` it upgrades everything you told it to be there.

Comment: Your point being? Anyway, I put the script as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This sorts all packages to install by their installation size:

```
apt-get -s dist-upgrade | awk '/^Inst/ { print $2 }' | xargs apt-cache --no-all-versions show | grep -E "^Package:|^Size:" | paste -s -d' \n' | sort -n -k 4
```

It is a rather long command which probably can be shortened by some more `awk` magic.

Answer (score 2):

Put this script in a file called something like `space-apt.sh` and run it using the same parameters you would pass to `apt-get`. It will show you (roughly) the difference in occupied space for each package.

For example:

```
% ./space-apt.sh install postfix
exim4                             -44 K
exim4-daemon-light              -1148 K
exim4-config                    -1089 K
exim4-base                      -1413 K
ssl-cert                         +101 K
postfix                         +3448 K
%
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for pkg in $(apt-get -s "$@" | grep '^Remv \|^Purg ' | cut -d' ' -f 2); do
    printf '%-30s %+6d K\n' $pkg \
        -$(dpkg-query -f '${Installed-Size}\t${Status}' -W $pkg \
           | grep ' installed$' \
           | cut -f 1)
done
for pkg in $(apt-get -s "$@" | grep '^Inst ' | cut -d' ' -f 2); do
    printf '%-30s %+6d K\n' $pkg \
        $(echo $(apt-cache --no-all-versions show $pkg \
                 | grep '^Installed-Size:' \
                 | tr -cd '0-9') - \
               0$(dpkg-query -f '${Installed-Size}\t${Status}' -W $pkg 2>/dev/null \
                  | grep ' installed$' \
                  | cut -f 1) \
          | bc)
done
```